# How to enable Administration menu Toolbar style for editor profile?

Tags: 7, routes, users, theming

I have created an Editor profile which can create specific content types. However, I would like to give such users the possibility of using the `Administration menu Toolbar style` (i.e. overlays) rather than the default page display.

Is this possible? If yes, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to grant a few permissions to the editor role to achieve this. Navigate to http://mysite.com/admin/people/permissions and tick the checkboxes next to the following permissions for the editor role:

- Use the administration toolbar
- Access the administrative overlay
- Use the administration pages and help
- View the administration theme

Only the pages that an editor user usually has access to will be shown as links in the toolbar.